# How to route `/username/app#app-state` in CloudFront / S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a web app, and I have path patterns that start with usernames, and the have the app and app state (or view). Like this:

```
example.com/username/app#list-view
```

Where the username will vary across users.

If I set this path pattern in CloudFront: `/*/app*` will it match the following requests?

```
example.com/joe/app#list-view
example.com/ello/app#item-view
```

If so, how do I get AWS S3 to give the same app.html file for any username?

Answer (score 1):

S3 is an object store, I don't think it's possible to serve the same file on multiple URLs easily. You might be able to use 301 redirects, but CloudFront will cache the redirect rather than following it. This seems like something that should be served from a web server.

Caching content customised for each user seems inadvisable. Routing it through CloudFlare is fine, just set your headers so it doesn't cache.

To provide a useful answer we'd need more context.